# Angular material mdc: any reasons mat-mdc-form-field-error-wrapper has :: before display: inline-block so that there is a huge padding?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, upgrade

To be able to upgrade to Angular 17 from 15, I upgraded angular material to angular material mdc. Some styles are broken now.

Now, there is a huge padding between the input text and the error. Angular material mdc mat-mdc-form-field-error-wrapper has :: before display: inline-block. If I replace inline-block with just inline, then it looks much better.

So, it has

```
.mat-mdc-form-field-bottom-align::before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 16px;
}
```

Any reasons why? What bad should happen if I replace

```
display: inline-block;
```

with

```
display: inline;
```

to meet my goal?

Answer (score 1):

Changing from `inline-block` to `inline` will just mean the height property will not have any effect, so you could just adjust the height directly, if you are worried about side effects on this change, also check your application once you make a change, everyone has their own opinion but validation in real time world (validating your application) is best for these types of changes!

```
.mat-mdc-form-field-bottom-align::before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 14px !important; //least height where the error moves up!
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dvxefs?file=package.json)